# <span> element using ImportXML with XPath in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the value of an element attribute from this [site](https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/soulflayer/item/168586) in Google Spreadsheet using XPath.

```
<span class="price money-gold">43.94</span>
```

I want to get value **43.94** but when i used

```
=IMPORTXML(A15;"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/table/tr[3]/td/span")
```

I get N/A

```
=IMPORTXML(A15;"//*[@class=’price money-gold’]")
```

I get N/A

Comment: GS cant inport JS content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2aGK.png